# Error: sdcard/hello.mp3: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, mobile, audio-player

I am testing the `"react-native-audio-recorder-player": "^3.5.3"` on Android 11 & 12 with the targetSDKversion 31 but it's showing me the error `Error: sdcard/sound.mp3: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)`
I have tried many solutions as suggested by many developers like adding `requestLegacyExternalStorage` permission in AndroidManifest file and also giving permission of `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` but still the error is same.

After decreasing the targetSDKversion to 29. App is working fine on Android 12 but since we can't upload it on Play Store, it's not useful and also some features becomes slow and lagged.

What should I do to make this feature work on Android 12 and above without decreasing the TargetSDKversion?

Can anybody help?

Comment: How did you got the url: sdcard/sound.mp3?

Comment: @user18309290 Exactly this was the error. I resolved this issue by changing this path with android: `${RNFS.CachesDirectoryPath}/hello.mp3`, it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by changing this path with android: `${RNFS.CachesDirectoryPath}/hello.mp3`, it worked for me.